# TableView fast multiple touch with Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a strange problem with Xcode tableViews. If I mash my finger multiple times on the same cell, it will stack multiple touches. In my particular case, I am pushing another view controller, but doing this will push more than one of the same. How do I solve this?

I have tried making the tableview not userinteractable in the didselectrow, but apparently the touches are logging simultaneously before even entering that method (like they're running in parallel or something).

Are there any simple ways to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably try setting the UITableView's `multipleTouchEnabled` property to `NO` or setting its `userInteractionEnabled` property to `NO`, do your processing then set the property back to `YES` once you've displayed the other view controller.

You can see the [Event Handling Guide for iOS: Multitouch Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH3-SW20) for more information.

I had to do something similar for a game I created. Users were able to double-tap one of the game board pieces which would trigger the code twice allowing a player to move twice in one turn in some cases. It was quite annoying.